# Global Python Logger with file Rotator

Tags: python, logging

I have create a global logger using the following:

```
def logini():
    logfile='/var/log/cs_status.log'
    import logging
    import logging.handlers
    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile,filemode='a',format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',datefmt='%y%m%d-%H:%M:%S',level=logging.DEBUG,propagate=0)
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=2000000, backupCount=5)
    logger.addHandler(handler)  
    __builtins__.logger = logger
```

It works, however I am getting 2 outputs for every log, one with the formatting and one without.

I realize that this is being caused by the file rotater as I can comment out the 2 lines of the handler code and then I get a single outputted correct log entry.

How can I prevent the log rotator from outputting   a second entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're configuring two file loggers that point to the same `logfile`. To only use the `RotatingFileHandler`, get rid of the `basicConfig` call:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=2000000,
                                               backupCount=5)
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

All `basicConfig` does for you is to provide an easy way to instantiate either a `StreamHandler` (default) or a `FileHandler` and set its loglevel and formats (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) for more information). If you need a handler other than these two, you should instantiate and configure it yourself.

Comment: Ahh, understood, I have tried your suggestion and it works, many thanks.